# Does 64-bit Windows XP provide compatibility with 32-bit exe files?

Tags: java, windows, windows-xp, 64-bit, compatibility

A customer cannot run our Java program. The shortcut executes a 32-bit copy of `javaw.exe` (the Java runtime) and then it passes the `.jar` file as a parameter (the Java program)

I am wondering if it is possibly caused by him running 64 bit XP. I do not know if it is 64 bit or not, but I know it is XP pro

This program is tested in XP 32 bit and Vista 32 bit and Win7 64bit (using the compatibility layer).

Does XP also have this compatibility layer?

Comment: Can you clarify on "Cannot run"? Does it crash? or does the OS simply refuse to run?

Comment: Windows XP x64 runs 32-bit Java just fine. Whatever problems they are running into is likely caused by something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes, it does](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896456):

> The 64-bit versions of Microsoft Windows Server 2003 and of Microsoft
>   Windows XP **use the Microsoft Windows-32-on-Windows-64 (WOW64)
>   subsystem to run 32-bit programs without modifications**. The 64-bit
>   versions of Windows Server 2003 and of Windows XP do not provide
>   support for 16-bit binaries or 32-bit drivers. Programs that depend on
>   16-bit binaries or 32-bit drivers cannot run on the 64-bit versions of
>   Windows Server 2003 or of Windows XP unless the program manufacturer
>   provides an update for the program.

Answer (score 0):

Many folks run 32-bit Java on 64-bit Windows (and other O/S's).  In general usage, performance is the same, sometimes better, than 64-bit Java, which comes into its own when programs need very large heaps.  It should be no problem.